# How to Display Multiple Lines of text using TextField in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I have created LWUIT `TextField`,and I've added paragraphs of text to my `TextField`,But I am not able to Display the Fulltext ?I am able to Display single line of text?
Here my Code:

```
   TextField field=new TextField(detailNews.getDescription());             
   field.setSingleLineTextArea(false);        
   field.setGrowByContent(true);       
   field.setIsScrollVisible(true);
   field.setFocus(false);
   field.setRows(detailNews.getDescription().length());     
   form2.addComponent(field);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextField`is only for a single line case. What you want to use is a `TextArea`Component.
So try to change your `TextField`component by a `TextArea` Component

Comment: hi,i have used TextArea,but i am not able to reduce the font,here my code:  TextArea big = new TextArea(detailNews.getDescription());
       Font createSystemFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL);
        big.getStyle().setFont(createSystemFont);

        big.setEditable(false);,How can i reduce Font?

Comment: Are you using the resource editor? It will be easy for you to change the propierties of your styles using the .res file

Comment: Can you answer this with piece of sample code,i downknow about that?

Comment: Th resource editor is a tool that helps you to create styles, interfaces, from a user friendly application. This could be exported in a .res file and used by code. You can start here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwZ98s4iiRU

Comment: Hi,i have created custom Font in Font.res file using resource.jar file,How can i apply the Font to my text area?

Comment: Ok, what you need to do now is the following:
Create a theme and add the font to the TextArea
If you want to change the font from code--->
Create another theme with the new font size and add it to the text area
You need to open the res from code
Resources res = Resources.open("/MyRes.res");
and later
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(res.getTheme("nameoftheme"));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15166/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-ragi-and-jmunoz)

Comment: hi,i have used the below code:
try { 
Resources res = Resources.open("/res/font.res"); 
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(res.getTheme("Font1")); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
i am facing java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: HI,i have generated my project using Resource Editor,but when i run my application ,i am facing Uncaught exception java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/XMLMidlet: com/sun/lwuit/events/ActionListener?...

Comment: What emulator are you using? Sun wireless toolkit 2.5.2 or higher? Import all the packets in the propierties of the emulator

Comment: i am using Nokia SDK 1.0 EMULATOR

Comment: Use this if you can please http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html